# hover selector when floating divs side by side

Tags: css, hover, css-float

I'm having problems with this:

[Jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ePWNg/1/)

As you can seen, when you hover over those divs, a border is added but it changes the dimensions and in some cases, the position of other divs.

In some sense, the amount of text is responsible for this (that is, if I place more or less the same number of characters in each div, everything works as expected), but I'd like to have some flexibility with respect to the content of each div.

How can I solve this?

Regards

Comment: +1 for a very common yet not widely known issue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to give it a white border initially and then change the border color. The W3 box model includes the border in the calculated width of DOM nodes, so when you add a border, it has to recalculate the width and adjust content.

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/ePWNg/5/

An alternative solution would be to remove the width and height of the border as you add it, like so:

```
#my_div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

#my_div:hover {
    width:98px; /* Minus 1px for top, 1px for bottom border */
    height:98px; /* Minus 1px for left, 1px for right border */
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the .preview following your suggestion (border: 1px solid white) , but it didn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You need the border to exist already, so that when a border is added it doesn't move over by the width of the border.

So what I have done is set the border as white, and then changed the right border back to the colour you had originally. Then on hover the whole border changes colour, so there is no need for your 1px margin correction. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ePWNg/6/

```
.preview{
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
    margin:0.2em;
    border: 1px solid white; /* this adds in the extra borders to begin with */
    border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.preview:hover {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Nope. But I have now! You must have posted it whilst I was in the midst of editing the fiddle and copying it over etc.

Comment: @tw16: Thanks for your answer. I think AlienWebguy posted earlier but thanks anyway :-)